# Comunication between ASP.Net Web Api and WPF application

Tags: wpf, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to let know wpf application that database is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SqlDependency, since it can raise an event (OnChange) in your code when the results of a query would change on the server (as the result of an INSERT or UPDATE from another user or process, for example)

An example of its use on CodeProject for a simple live chat application:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx

another way of doing this is using something like a live connection between your wpf application and your web-api , i recommend something like signalr you can find resources here:
http://www.asp.net/signalr